# ggplot plots in scripts do not display in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I have a strange issue with Rstudio: If a script calls ggplot2 functions to display a plot, then using *Source* to run the script does not produce the plots. If I select the whole script with `Ctrl+A`, then *Run the current line or selection* (`Ctrl+Enter`), then the plot *does* display. Likewise, typing plotting commands into the console produces correct output.

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)

p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point()
```

Will only produce output if pasted into console, not if sourced.

There are other questions about this, but neither is helpful:

- [ggplot2 ggsave function causes graphics device to not display plots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16472935/1042555) falsely claims the issue is fixed in newer versions, it has not.
- [RStudio - ggplot not saving first plot when printing and saving multiple plots in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16489570/1042555) was closed as a duplicate, yet not only is it not a duplicate, but the `dev.off()` workaround doesn't work ("`Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)`")

How can I get Rstudio to display plots when a script is sourced? I am using Rstudio  0.98.1062 and R 3.1.1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recently happened on this question and realized that the most up to date way is to call `show(p)` after creating the plot.

Comment: Do you have any sources that this is the most up to date way? All I can find is this: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/print.ggplot.html

Answer (score 156):

The solution is to explicitly call `print()` on ggplot object:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p <- p + geom_point()
print(p)
```

`ggplot` function returns object of class ggplot; ggplot2 works by overloading `print` function to behave differently on objects of class ggplot - instead of printing them to STDOUT, it creates chart.

Everything is working well in interactive mode, because R assumes that most of commands are run through `print()` function. This is for our convenience and allows us to type `rnorm(1)` and get any visible output. When Run current selection command is used (`Ctrl+Enter`), RStudio behaves as if each selected line was typed in interactive mode and run. You can verify that by checking your command history in `Console` pane after running few selected lines.

But this convenient mode is abandoned when file is read by `source()`. Since this function is intended to run (potentially long and computationally-expensive) R scripts, it is undesirable to pollute STDOUT with low-priority messages. That's why `source()` by default will output only error message. If you want anything else, you have to explicitly ask for that.

Comment: I hate how all these tutorial sites don't even mention you have to call print. Source: https://datacarpentry.org/R-ecology-lesson/04-visualization-ggplot2.html

Comment: @NoName I am in total agreement with you. Also, I disagree with the design specification that makes "print" necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 24):

though it's a quite old question. I had the same problem and found a quick solution, if you want to use "source" button on R studio edit box.

you can simply turn on "source with echo" (Ctrl + Shift + Enter) and the plot shows as expected

Comment: Great, didn't knew that! That adds nicely to the explanation given by @Mirosław Zalewski.

Answer (score 7):

I found this question when searching a similar problem (plots not showing up in RStudio). I was trying to troubleshoot a complicated ggplot2 block by running it in parts, but couldn't get anything to show up in the plot window.

Reason: the `tiff()` function I opened earlier had not closed.

Solution: I ran `dev.off()` a few times until all my earlier `tiff()` functions completed, then I was able to create plots in RStudio and view the results in the plot window.

Comment: Thanks Tania, saved me a restart... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is simply using `plot()`. When clicking on "Source" in Rstudio, it show the plot in the window like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p = p + geom_point()
plot(p) 

# This pops when clicking on Source
source("~/.active-rstudio-document")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I find that 'plot()' does not accept/recognize a 'ggproto object' as input!!