# How to display a series of plots in R based on a variable taking values from sequence?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display a series of plots in R based on a condition with a variable taking a sequence of values something like simple clustering. I have data frame with numerical columns X and Y respectively. There is also a Z column with text values (categorical variable).
I am trying the following code but it doesn't work. The code works fine if instead I use numerical values for i and j, example i=50 and j=100.

> my data frame: **new.data**,  columns: **X, Y, Z**

```
 j=0
 for(i in seq(0, 500, by = 50)){
   j=i+50
   PlotData <- new.data[(new.data$X <j) & (new.data$X >i),]
   ggplot (PlotData, aes(X, Y, color = Z)) + geom_point()
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to explicitly print the plot in the loop. Replacing the `ggplot()` line with this should work:

```
p <- ggplot (PlotData, aes(X, Y, color = Z)) + geom_point()
print(p)
```

Setting i, j individually rather than in a loop works because the print statement is run implicitly outside the brackets. See this post for details: [ggplot plots in scripts do not display in Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643852/ggplot-plots-in-scripts-do-not-display-in-rstudio)