# How to render ggplot from a function that returns a list of multiple objects in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-server

I have an r script includes a Identify_IP() that returns a list of dataframe and a ggplot. I want to call the script and render both the dataframe and the plot.

This is Identify_IP() function. I took off unrelative code and kept only the plot, lines and ggplot code to give a clear example of my type of ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(matrixStats)
library(fda.usc)

#df <- read.table("name.XLS", header = FALSE)

Identify_IP = function(df1){
  mlearn <- df1[,'V7']
     formul <- plot(blue_curve$x, blue_curve$y * 30, type = 'l', col = 'blue')

  formula_deriv <- lines(blue_curve$x, red_curve$y1 * 30, col = 'red')

  p <- ggplot(df1, aes(blue_curve$x)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = blue_curve$y, colour = "0 Deriv")) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = red_curve$y1, colour = "1st Deriv")) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = x_loc) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)


  return(list(df1,p))

}
```

Now, this is a modified Shiny code based on amrr and micstr suggestion.

```
 source('InflectionP2.R', local = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Upload your file"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xls file',
                    accept = c(".XLS")),

      actionButton("btn", "Update Table"),
      actionButton("btn1", "Display Plot")

    ),

    mainPanel(

      tableOutput('what'),
      plotOutput('pl'))
  )

)
,

server = function(input, output, session){

  dataOP <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(input$file1))
      return(NULL)

    dfs <- Identify_IP(read.table(inFile$datapath))

    return(dfs)
  })


  observeEvent(input$btn, output$what <-  renderTable({

    dataOP()[[1]]

  }))

  observeEvent(input$btn1, output$pl <- renderPlot({

    pp <- dataOP()

    pp[[2]]

  }))             
}))
```

This was really helpful in teaching me how to call r script in reactive(). And it makes sense to me. Yet, it render the table but the Display Plot button is not rendering the plot. Does my ggplot in Identify_IP function has anything to do with not being able to display the plot? I also tried print(ggplot(pp[[2]])) and still the same.

Comment: How are you returning ggplot in that function? just an assignment like `p <- ggplot()` ?

Comment: And I couldn't see any plot in `dataOP()` It's just `dfs` for both `tble` and `plt`

Comment: Yes for the first question. As for the second, this is what I am stuck with. I really don't know how to pass the plot. I tried different methods and nothing worked so far.

Comment: Could you please share the code where you create `ggplot()`

Comment: Let me understand, you are already creating ggplot inside Identify_IP or you want to create one inside the reactive function in `server.R`?

Comment: I already created one inside Identify_IP which return(df, ggplot). I am able to run the ggplot on Rstudio but I need to render it on server.R just by calling Identify_IP (). But I don't know how to pass the arguments, create a list of them, then finally ggplot  on shinyApp

Comment: Okay, Try this: return a list of them; let's say you stored your plot in `p`. so now `new_list = list(df,p); return(new_list)` 

here on server.R, try to access the first element of the list for df and second for plot

Comment: Sorry for my question. But this is part of the issue I am trying to fix. I do not know the syntax to access the arguments. How does Identify_IP() passes the arguments. 
I tried this dfs <- Identify_IP(read.table(inFile$datapath))
        new_list = list(df ,p);
        return(new_list) })  observeEvent(input$btn, output$what <-  renderTable({dataOP()$df}))
      
      observeEvent(input$btn1, output$pl <- renderPlot({
        print(ggplot(dataOP()$p))

Comment: I think you might need to share the code in `Identify_IP` for us to help. Try to create a min reproducible example of the issue.

Comment: Simple - but I assume you have a `library(ggplot2)` call somewhere...?

Comment: Note there is an extra comma after `"Display Plot"),` that needs to go

Comment: I modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working.

Note I used the internal data set `iris` and made a toy `Identify_IP` function as I do not have your code.

Note you still need to choose a file to trigger the events but it will ignore that file and use `iris` data.

Workaround I used `[[1]]` to get the table not `dataOP()$tble`

**CODE**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# source('InflectionP2.R', local = TRUE)
# MAKE TEST FUNCTION
Identify_IP <- function(mydata) {

  #shrink data
  tble <- head(mydata)

  plt <-  ggplot(data = head(mydata),
                 mapping = aes(y = Sepal.Length,
                               x = Petal.Length)) + geom_point()

  return(list(tble, plt))
}




runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Upload your file"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xls file',
                    accept = c(".XLS")),

          actionButton("btn", "Update Table"),
          actionButton("btn1", "Display Plot")

        ),

        mainPanel(

          tableOutput('what'),
          plotOutput('pl'))
      )

    )
    ,

    server = function(input, output, session){

      dataOP <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(input$file1))
          return(NULL)

        # ORIGINAL dfs <- Identify_IP(read.table(inFile$datapath))
        # using internal dataset for example
        dfs <- Identify_IP(iris)

        # ORIGINAL list(tble = dfs, plt = dfs)
        # lets just return your dfs, its already a list in code above
        return(dfs)
      })


      observeEvent(input$btn, output$what <-  renderTable({

        #print(dataOP()) # debug line that led to [[1]] idea
        # ORIGINAL  dataOP()$tble
        # just say first in list
        dataOP()[[1]]

        }))

      observeEvent(input$btn1, output$pl <- renderPlot({


        #ggplot(dataOP()$plt)
        # since already a plot just need to index it
        # I found [[2]] worked better than explicit dataOP()$plt
        pp <- dataOP()

        pp[[2]]

      }))             
    }))
```

**RESULT**

[image: table and plot example]

Voila!

Comment: It makes sense to me. It still doesn't work. I will modify my code above and display Identify_IP() and the ggplot it returns.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try `print (ggplot(dataOP()$plt))`

Take a look at [this answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46037472/4606130).

2) Sorry its hard to interpret without your `ggplot` code bit and data. Given @amrrs questions can you try debug in your Shiny code with `print()` and `str()` temporary lines to see what your data is returning. i.e.

```
print(dataOP()$plt)
str(dataOP())
```

Worse case, try split your code in two. So Identify_IP code to do the data leg and then make a Print_IP with the ggplot code that just returns the plot. It might rule out your chart is not the problem.

3) Take a look at `reactiveValues()`

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/reactiveValues.html

It "bakes" a result that was reactive. The type coming out of your chart may be a reactive type not a chart type. Perhaps share any error messages you are getting.

Comment: Not working. I'm wondering if I'm passing the objects correctly in the List inside reactive function. I think the problem is that I don't know how to pass the arguments.

Comment: MarJamil i think this answer may be very useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24899084/4606130. Inside your renderPlot() take `dd <- dataOP()$plt` do your `p <- ggplots(dd etc)` on dd and then `print(p)`