# Why does pdf() plot, dev.off() succeed but the same commands within a function call fail?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, seurat

The following set of commands will print an appropriately formatted pdf file with the data represented, and this is the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Seurat/versions/3.1.4/topics/DimPlot) for `Dimplot`. It runs appropriately and all the required packages load fine.

```
project_name<-"my_project"
file_stem<-" my_dim_plot_"
fig_name<-paste0(figure_dir, "/", file_stem, project_name, ".pdf")
base_plot<-DimPlot(combined_data_obj, reduction = "tsne", label = TRUE) + NoLegend()
ggsave(fig_name, width = 20, height = 16, units = "cm", device='pdf')
base_plot
dev.off()
```

Why, then, does this code print an empty pdf?

```
save_ggplot_figure<-function(plot_object, figure_dir, file_stem, project_name) {
# Need to add functionality for mutiple plots, different file extensions, etc.
  fig_name<-paste0(figure_dir, "/", file_stem, project_name, ".pdf")
  ggsave(fig_name, width = 20, height = 16, units = "cm", device='pdf')
  plot_object
  dev.off()
}

project_name<-"my_project"; file_stem<-"tsne_dim_plot_"; project_name<-"my_project"
base_plot<-DimPlot(combined_data_obj, reduction = "tsne", label = TRUE) + NoLegend()
save_ggplot_figure(base_plot, figure_dir, file_stem, project_name)
```

The only difference I can see is that the commands to print the plot then turn `dev.off()` are inside a function call, but why should this matter?
I tried the same code using `pdf()` instead of `ggsave()`, but with the same results (it prints a 4kb) empty pdf file instead of the 120kb pdf file printed when the commands are printed outside the function call.

Comment: use `print(plot_object)`.

Comment: Please confirm that https://stackoverflow.com/q/26643852/3358272 resolved your problem, as I believe you're talking about a well-known "thing" with `ggplot2` plots.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `dev.off()` after using `ggsave`. But you may want to pass the actual `plot_object` to `ggsave`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ggsave wrongly, the first argument should always be the object, then you specify the file name. Hence you get an empty file because `ggsave()` is trying to create a pdf on something that doesn't exist. So if you change the function to:

```
save_ggplot_figure<-function(plot_object, figure_dir, file_stem, project_name) {

  fig_name<-paste0(figure_dir, "/", file_stem, project_name, ".pdf")
  ggsave(plot_object, file = fig_name, 
  width = 20, height = 16, units = "cm", device='pdf')

}
```

This should work. and you don't need to call `dev.off()`