# Why does R conditional compilation fail using ggplot?

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, tikzdevice

Edit: This question has been flagged as a duplicate of another question related to Rstudio. I would like to clarify that I am running this file with the command `R -f figures.R` and have never used Rstudio before. While some answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/27201707/118153 appear to  be relevant, it does not answer why the code operates fine without the `if`. Answers to the linked question would appear to imply it should not work at all, while it does work without the `if`.

I would like to selectively build figures for my paper, regenerating only those which I have deleted. However, the following code produces a `.tex` file with only two comment lines; when run without the `if` around it, it correctly produces the whole file. I am an R novice - this core code itself comes from a statistical consultant.

Why does the following code not produce the figure when inside an `if`, but it produces the figure when not inside an `if`?

```
figure <- '../paper/figures/recall_by_choices.tex'
if (!file.exists(figure)) {
    tikz(file=figure,width=3.5, height=2)
    mem1percent <- mem |>
        group_by(choices, success1) |>
        summarize(count=n()) |>
        mutate(Percent = count/sum(count) * 100)
    mem1percent |>
        ggplot(aes(x=factor(choices), y=Percent, fill=success1)) +
        geom_bar(stat='identity', position=position_dodge(), color='black') +
        labs(x="Choices", fill="7-day Recall") +
        scale_fill_manual(values=c('black','grey'))
    dev.off()
}
```

A similar example appears to run fine within an `if`, not using `ggplot`:

```
figure <- '../paper/figures/hmn_density.tex'
if (!file.exists(figure)) {
    tikz(file=figure,width=7, height=4)
    hmn <- table(ifelse(surveys$how_many == 'own' | surveys$how_many == 'n/a' | surveys$how_many == 'lots' | surveys$how_many == '', NA, ifelse(surveys$how_many == 'inf' | nchar(surveys$how_many) > 5, 100000, as.numeric(surveys$how_many))))
    plot(density(hmn), main='', xlab='Number of Choices')
    dev.off()
}
```

Perhaps `ggplot` is causing the problem? Both give output with warnings when the `if` condition is true:

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'choices'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
null device 
          1
```

```
null device 
          1 
Warning message:
In ifelse(surveys$how_many == "inf" | nchar(surveys$how_many) >  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Does it help if you explicitly print by declaring `plot <- ...your plot code...` followed by `print(plot)`?

Comment: @teunbrand yes. I can update the file to use this approach; does this reveal anything about the underlying cause?

Comment: The principals provided in the answers from the linked duplicate are not specific to Rstudio, which is just an IDE for R - those answers are still relevant

Comment: The underlying cause is that R has some behaviors that are different in interactive use vs. inside a function or inside an `if`. One of those differences is whether an graphical object that is generated is automatically also displayed to the graphic device. Outside of interactive use, you may need to `print` the object for it to show up. The linked duplicate is a similar manifestation of that situation, though it could probably say more about the why.

Comment: If you can mentally find/replace "`for`" for "`if`", [this is perhaps a better dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716380/903061), or the official [R FAQ 7.16](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-is-the-output-not-printed-when-I-source_0028_0029-a-file_003f). The behavior isn't specific to `ggplot`s and `if` statements (with or without RStudio). All automatic printing of R objects without an explicit `print()` is disabled in most cases. That it works in interactive use is the exception, but it reverts to no-printing-default in functions, loops, non-interactive sessions, etc.